# Downsampling in sklearn. Test and Train performance question

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science-model, class-imbalance

I have a class imbalanced data set, and have the following set up to handle class imbalance. I first split to test and train and only perform downsampling on the training set and then get the test scores on the test set where there is imbalance.
I get a training score that is lower than my test score. Is this common or am I doing something wrong?

My training score is around .77 accuracy and my test score is around 0.82 accuracy.

```
from numpy import unique
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.utils import resample

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(url, header=None)


train_data = dataframe.sample(frac = 0.8)
test_data = dataframe.drop(train_data.index)


df_majority = train_data[train_data.iloc[: , -1] == 0]
df_minority = train_data[train_data.iloc[: , -1] == 1]

df_majority_downsampled = resample(df_majority, replace = True, n_samples = df_minority.shape[0], random_state = 123)
df_downsampled = pd.concat([df_minority, df_majority_downsampled])


X_train, y_train = df_downsampled.iloc[:,:-1], df_downsampled.iloc[:,-1:]
X_test, y_test = test_data.iloc[:,:-1], test_data.iloc[:,-1:]


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear', random_state = 42).fit(X_train, y_train)
print(clf.score(X_train,y_train))

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(clf.score(X_test,y_test))
```

Comment: [Are you sure you need to downsample at all?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any)

Comment: You're using accuracy, which [isn't a great measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/232706), especially in imbalanced situations.  Are you sure that's the metric of interest (and FPs and FNs are equally bad)?